# How to customize a legend in highcharts as the image and while clicking on the leg end appears lines inside linechart

Tags: highcharts

```js
Highcharts.chart('myChart', {
  chart:{
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    //polar: true,
    height: 615,
    type: 'line',
    //marginTop: 27 ,
    margin: [90, 10, 90, 10]
  },
  title: {
    style: {
        display: 'none'
    }
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },

    

    yAxis: {
      tickPixelInterval: 50,
      offset: -19,
       floor: 0,
       ceiling: 100,
       gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
       gridLineColor: '#676767',
       title: {
       text: null
      },
      
      labels: {
            style: {
                color: 'red'
            },
            y: -8,
            x: 0,
            
            format: '{value} %'
       },
     
      
    },
    xAxis: {
     tickmarkPlacement:'on',
      type: 'category',
        categories: ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'],
        max: 11,
        gridLineColor: '#686868',
        gridLineWidth: 1,
      //offset: 50,
      
        tickLength: 0,
        
        lineColor: 'transparent',
        
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: 'red'
            },
            x: 5,
            //offset: -50
         }
    },
    
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
          lineWidth: 3,
          marker: {
                enabled: false
            },    
            label: {
                enabled: false
            },
            states: {
                // hover: {
                //     enabled: true,
                //     lineWidth: 10
                // },
                 
            },
            events:{
              click: function (event) {
                lineWidth: 5

                //event.point.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(e.point, e)
              }
            },
            
        }
    },

    series: [{
       name: 'PR',
        data: [10,67,88],
        color: '#35FEDB',
        
        marker: {
          states: {
              hover: {
                  enabled: false
              }
          }
        },
       
    }, {
        name: 'PREV',
        data: [1, 9,27, 40, 57, 69, 93],
        color: '#7EFF75',
        
        marker: {
          states: {
              hover: {
                  enabled: false
              }
          }
        },
    }, {
        name: 'GO',
        data: [0, 28, 40, 42, 65, 69, 82],
        color: '#EF4556',
        
        marker: {
          states: {
              hover: {
                  enabled: false
              }
          }
        },
    }, {
        name: 'Demo',
        data: [0, 30,45, 45, 68, 88, 92],
        color: 'white',
       
        marker: {
          states: {
              hover: {
                  enabled: false
              }
          }
        },
    }],
    
    tooltip: {
      shared: false,
        useHTML: true,
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor:'transparent',
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '13px',
            padding: 0,
      },
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.series.name == 'PR') {
            
            $('.cyan-tooltip').text('PR '+this.y+'%');
             return '<div class="pr-tooltip-head"style="color: black; background: #35FEDB; height: 80px; text-align: center; width: 190px; left: -7px;  position: relative; padding: 5px;">' + this.series.name + 
                        '<br/>'+ this.y +'%'+'</div>' 
                       ;
                    
          }
          else if (this.series.name == 'PREV') {
            $('.green-tooltip').html('PREVENDAS '+this.y+'%');
             return '<div class="prevtooltip-head"style="color: black; background: #7EFF75; height: 80px; text-align: center; width: 190px; left: -7px;  position: relative; padding: 5px;">' + this.series.name + 
                        '<br/>'+ this.y +'%'+'</div>' 
                       ;
          }
          else if (this.series.name == 'GOB') {
            $('.red-tooltip').html('GO '+this.y+'%');
             return '<div class="go-tooltip-head" style="color: $secondary; background: #EF4556; height: 200px; text-align: left; width: 190px; left: -7px;  position: relative; padding: 5px;">' + this.series.name + 
                        '<br/>'+'Objetivo\'17'+'<br/>'+ '4.250.000.00'+ '<br/>'+'Objetivo Nov\'17'+'<br/>' + '<span class="seperator"></span><div style="text-align:center">'+ this.y +'%'+'</div>'+'</div>' 
                       ;
          }
          else if (this.series.name == 'Demo') {
             return '<div class="demo-tooltip-head"style="color: black; background: $secondary; height: 80px; text-align: center; width: 190px; left: -7px;  position: relative; padding: 5px;">' + this.series.name + 
                        '<br/>'+ this.y +'%'+'</div>' 
                       ;
          }
          else return false;
      },
        
    },
    
     responsive: {
         rules: [{
             condition: {
                 Width: 200
             },
            
         }]
     }

});
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function (proceed, point, e) {
        if (e && e.type !== 'mousemove') {
            proceed.call(this, point, e);
        }
    });
    H.addEvent(H.Point.prototype, 'click', function (e) {

        e.point.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(e.point, e);

        //e.point.series.chart.lineWidth.refresh(10);
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

```html
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

How to customize a legend in highcharts as given in image.

[image]

And place it right to the given line chart

[image]

Now I created a line chart using highchart. And it has 3 lines. While loading the chart all lines are visible. And now I want to make:

1. Invisible each line while clicking on corresponding colors in required legend.That is while clicking on red spot make invisible the red line.
2. And make visible by clicking again on the red spot.Similarly for rest of lines in the chart.
3. When red spot is clicked make other spot to see as disabled but not 
    completely
4. chart must not be shown empty, minimum accepted 1 line chart

[Inside the green region y-axis value to be displayed while hovering green spot after clicking on the green line.Until clicking the line disable the hovering property.This is similar to all other colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xQo0.jpg)

Comment: Can you please share the current code you have; just to simplify us helping you :)

Comment: ok i will provide

Comment: Entered the code i have done for line chart and given image for legend is simply <ul><li> elements

Comment: Anyone can help me   regarding the above mentioned case

Comment: Could you explain more specifically the **3rd** point? This requirement refers only to the red series? How should the disabled state look like?

Comment: In the first image, we can see 4 spots.While clicking on red spot make the  other 3 sports blurred

Comment: The given code was very useful for me.It worked. Thank you very much.But still, I want help. 1) The legend is now showing over the chart and I want to place the created legend to the right of the chart. 2) while hovering the colored spot after clicking on the corresponding colored line inside the line chart the data(y-axis value) from each line should be visible on the spot respectively

Comment: I will explain in detail the above requirement.That is:suppose i clicked on red line inside line chart , then the y-axis value at that point should be visible while hovering the red spot.Similarly for other lines also.Since no value get before clicking on the lines, disable the hovering effect for spots before clicking on the line and enable hovering effect for spots after clicking on the line

Comment: My requirement is  While hovering over any of the spots in custom legend Nothing is visible now.It is also okay.But while clicking on any of the points in any of the colored line and hovering on the corresponding colored spot in custom legend, make visible the value at the y-axis where we clicked last in the hover area.                                                          
                                                                                                              How to achieve this?

Comment: Anyone can help me regarding the above mentioned case

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/zp7rjzx3/

I create and configure custom legend in `chart.events.load`:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {

        // legend box
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', 'legend-box');
        document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-container')[0].appendChild(div);

        // items
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.setAttribute('class', 'item-list');
        div.appendChild(ul);

        this.series.forEach(function(s) {
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.setAttribute('class', 'menu-item');

          li.style.color = s.color;

          ul.appendChild(li);
            li.addEventListener('click', function() {
            s.setVisible();
          });
        });

      }
    }
  }
```

Associated **CSS**:

```
#container {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 600px;
}

.legend-box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #455;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 500px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item-list {
  margin: 20px 0 0 5px;
}

.menu-item {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

`setVisible` method serves for toggling visibility of a series.

You can easily implement other functionalities using this demo as starting point.

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible

Comment: Let me know if I understood you correctly. Example from my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/zp7rjzx3/ Is that what you're trying to achieve?: If I hover the orange spot from the custom legend (box with rounded corners) and nothing happens because any point on the plot hasn't been clicked yet. Then I click point (x: 0, y: 2) on the orange line and hover the orange spot in the custom legend. The point that I clicked should be highlighted somehow, right? How orange line should look now?

Comment: *make visible the value at the y-axis in the hover area* - how exactly do you expect it to look?
Should a point marker be added (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.marker) to the previously clicked point?

Comment: This demo shows how to access custom legend element on point click (`plotOptions.series.point.events.click`): http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/04e4syar/ For example purposes I implemented changing of the legend's item color to yellow - you should implement your own styles / DOM modifications.

Comment: This line is responsible for setting class for `li` elements:           `li.setAttribute('class', 'menu-item');` You can change the `'menu-item'` string to individual value for every item.

Comment: when I give three different names all li elements take the last li element's class name                                                                                                                 
   Eg:  var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.setAttribute('class', 'menu-item-1');
          li.setAttribute('class', 'menu-item-2');
          li.setAttribute('class', 'menu-item-3');
          li.style.color = s.color;                                                                           Class Name taking by all li elements is : "menu-item-3"

Comment: Please provide a live demo of this issue.

Comment: When hovering first li element I want some text to show over the li element.While hovering second li element another different content to visible.And for third li element also.But now all li element has same class name and all show same text so my aim not get satisfied

Comment: This code will create a separate class for every item:      `this.series.forEach(function(s, i) {
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.setAttribute('class', 'menu-item-' + (i + 1)); (...) }`

Comment: Above code worked.And now i want to include span element inside each li element.And after clicking any colored line inside the line chart and hovering the li element (colored spot on right) I want to display the y-axis value of the clicked point in the newly created span

Comment: Help needed.Now on clicking the colored spot in custom legend, once the corresponding colored line will get invisible.If I click all colored spots, all lines will disappear and the entire chart itself disappear.So now I want to make visible at least one line visible inside line chat.And to make visible chart always

Comment: Hello, Any way to help?